# Chain to resources created with count in Terraform

Tags: terraform

How do I chain to resource(s) created with count? Or should I not created them with `count` if I want to chain additional resources to them? Doing it the way below, with `count` used in the initial resource and `for_each` used in the chained resource gives me the following error:

```
The given "for_each" argument value is unsuitable: the "for_each" argument must be a map, or set of strings, and you have provided a value of type number.
```

I understand why this error occurs, but I also am confused on the best practice here.

```
resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl" "waf_acl_regional" {
  count       = var.env == "prod" ? 1 : 0
  name        = "${var.project}-${var.env}"
  description = "A simple WAF ACL for ${var.env} environment."
  scope       = "REGIONAL"

  default_action {
    allow {}
  }

  rule {
    ...
  }

  visibility_config {
    ...
  }
}

resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl_association" "example" {
  for_each     = aws_wafv2_web_acl.waf_acl_regional
  resource_arn = aws_lb.hasura.arn
  web_acl_arn  = each.value.arn
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Basically, you have said the `aws_wafv2_web_acl` to use `count` meta-argument, which as the name suggests uses numbers. It creates an array where you can access elements by referencing the element of the array. In your case that would be `aws_wafv2_web_acl.waf_acl_regional[0]`. On the other hand, `for_each` meta-argument uses key/value pairs. That means that in order to fetch a value, you have to have a key which will be used. For example, that would be something like `aws_wafv2_web_acl.waf_acl_regional["prod"]`. That further means you would have to create a variable of type `map` or `set`.

Comment: @MarkoE Why not put your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to project from what `count` produces into what `for_each` needs you will need to write a slightly more elaborate expression to explain to Terraform which keys it should use to identify the instances.

For example, if the `name` argument of `aws_wafv2_web_acl` is suitably unique to identify all instances of that particular resource, you could write a [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/for) to project the list of objects into a map where the keys are the `name` values:

```
  for_each = {
    for acl in aws_wafv2_web_acl.waf_acl_regional : acl.name => acl
  }
```

This relies on the fact that a `count` resource produces a list, which is a suitable value to project using a `for` expression. When doing this, it's important to select an attribute whose value is defined statically in the configuration, rather than chosen dynamically by a remote system during the apply step. For example, the `id` attribute of many resource types is a unique ID chosen dynamically by the remote system, and so that would not be a suitable value to use as a `for_each` key.

That's important because Terraform will need to know the value during the plan phase in order to explain which resource instances the plan would create when applied.

Comment: Awesome, this is what I was looking for. Is this best practice though? Or would you do it another way, and not use count at all?

Answer (score 5):

You have instructed the `aws_wafv2_web_acl` resource to use the `count` meta-argument [1], which as the name suggests uses numbers. It creates an array where you can access elements by referencing the element of the array. In your case that would be `aws_wafv2_web_acl.waf_acl_regional[0]`. On the other hand, the `for_each` meta-argument [2] uses key/value pairs. That means that in order to fetch a value, you have to have a key which will be used as a reference to a value. For example, that would be something like `aws_wafv2_web_acl.waf_acl_regional["prod"]`. That further means that the `var.env` would have to be of type `map` or `set` [3]. Those types are complex types in Terraform.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/count

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each

[3] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/type-constraints#complex-types

Comment: Thank so much.  Given that I am using count with this conditional, `var.env == "prod" ? 1 : 0`, how would I configure the chained resource to also use this conditional but loop through all elements? It would be nice to make it dynamic in case the `count` were more than 1.

Comment: I would think that using `length` with `count` would be the most "dynamic" combination. E.g., create a list of environments in which you want to deploy WAF and set `count = length(var.envs)`.